# Auth::attempt not working in laravel 5.2 missing

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I'm missing something it shows me throw an internal server error.

Routes.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function() {

    Route::post('/signup',[
        'uses' => 'UserController@postSignUp',//SignupProcess
        'as' => 'signup'
        ]);

    Route::post('/signin',[
        'uses' => 'UserController@postSignIn',//SigninProcess
        'as' => 'signin'
        ]);

});


Route::get('signup', function () {
    return view('signup');
});

Route::get('login', function () {
    return view('login');
});
```

UserController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function postSignUp(Request $request)
    {
        $username = $request['username'];
        $password = bcrypt($request['password']);
        $token = $request['_token'];

        $user = new user();
        $user->email = $username;
        $user->password = $password;
        $user->remember_token = $token;

        $user->save();

        return redirect()->back();
    }

    public function postSignIn(request $request)
    { 

          if (Auth::attempt(['email'=> $request['username'], 'password' => $request['password']]))
           {
            // Authentication passed...
            return "false";
           }
    }
 }
```

User.php(model)

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;



    class User extends Model implements Authenticable
    {

        use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticable;

    }
```

login.blade.php

```
<html>
<head><title>Login</title></head>
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'signin']) !!}
    <label>Username</label>
    <input type = "text" name = "username"> <br>
    <label> Password </label>
    <input type = "password" name = "password"><br>

    <input type='hidden' name='_token' value='{{ Session::token()}}'>
    <input type = "submit" name = "Login">
{!! Form::close() !!}
</body>
```

signup.blade.php

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'signup']) !!}
<html>
<head><title>Login</title></head>
<form>
    <label>Username</label>
    <input type = "text" name = "username"> <br>
    <label> Password </label>
    <input type = "password" name = "password"><br>
    <input type = "submit" name = "Login">
</form>
</body>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

2 then use this to for authentication [LINK](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#authentication-quickstart) 
if you want use manual way in your login form use

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/login') }}">
```